# Numbers of heptagons of size 1 inside a square

Tags: geometry

How many heptagons of unit size can be put inside a square?
What I have done so far: thinking and yet have no idea.

Comment: Inside of a square of dimensions?

Comment: For an upper bound you can pack heptagons in circles and [circles in squares](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/cirinsqu/).